# Uncaught Error: invalid address when transferring token

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

When I try to transfer the token from 1 address to another, the error in the title pops up.
Here is my relevant JS code:
($("#targetAddr").val() is the address of the target address (in metamask) and  $("#amt").val() is the value of the tokens to transfer to.)

```
tokenContract.transfer($("#targetAddr").val().toString(),$("#amt").val())
```

I am using a smart contract that is very similar to OpenZepplin's ERC20. Its transfer is similar to ERC20's transfer function. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code of my token contract setup in javascript:

```
var tokenContractAddress = token_contract_address;
//coinABI is the ABI from my smart contract.
var tokenContract = web3.eth.contract(coinABI).at(tokenContractAddress);
```

The address that is in the input is one of the addresses in my metamask account (essentially a valid address)

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct an actual transaction with web3 or other framework you're using.
Here is an example with web3:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24828/how-to-send-erc20-token-using-web3-api

If you have a different version, go to their docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/index.html

And see methods for sending a transaction to a contract.
You need to send a tx to the token contract that will call token's native `transfer()` method with neede arguments. you will need to sign this transaction and then send it.

Comment: thks but looks like i was careless in my code (all is good now)